# How to create dynamic id and then a link to a post population on a carousel with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I would like the population on a post carousel to send me to a link and not to the post, and when is expired to be deleted automatically. You should know I'm not an expert in javascript, I did this very basic.

This is the page https://thecrescentbeachclub.com/events/upcoming-events/ and I don't know if someone can help me improve this code, or maybe create another one.

The client adds posts with featured images and then we use this module to show a carousel (they like the way is displayed now, you should know I didn't do this website neither so has been hard to change the clients mind), and when I added an automatic expirer that when the event finishes the post is deleted, all good here. The situation is that on the link I sent you I added the next code for a link because I don't want people to go to the post, I want them to go to an external link.

```
jQuery(function($){
$('.qode-bct-posts .qode-bct-post').each(function(){
$(this).attr('id',$(this).index()+1);
});

$('.qode-bct-posts .qode-bct-post .qode-bct-post-image img').each(function(){
$(this).unwrap();
});

$('#1').wrap('<a style="width: 100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;" href="https://www.eventbrite.com/e/easter-at-the-beach-buffet-brunch-tickets-58504343065" target="_blank" itemprop="url"></a>');

$('#2').wrap('<a style="width: 100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;" href="#" target="_blank" itemprop="url"></a>');

$('#3').wrap('<a style="width: 100%; display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;" href="#" target="_blank" itemprop="url"></a>');

});
```

Now the issue is that when a post is deleted automatically, the link is wrong, for example, the first post has ID 1 with that link, but when expires disappears, and now the post with ID 2 has the link on 1. I have to change the link manually, and that's what we want to avoid.

Can somebody help me to make the ID dynamic so when a post expires the and disappear the others still will keep the right link? I hope I explained myself.

Comment: Why can't you just delete the html for that element from the carousal instead.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I understand your question. The problem is not to delete, the problem is to be deleted automatically when the post expires. Would you elaborate more about your suggestion?

Comment: What I understood from your question was how to delete the particular element from carousal, which will remove the link as well not passing in to other carousal element present. Correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: I actually added a plugin that deletes automatically expired posts, but the link is added with the code above, so it's not tied really, but since you mention it, a code that deletes the post and the link will be great instead of a plugin, but I don't have any idea how can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended finding a plugin that will let me add an external link to the post, instead of the post itself, so I don’t need to make this code work. I didn’t want because WordPress get all crazy when you add more plugins, but the client is happy, so I’m happy. Thanks for you help though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to remove a specific Id element from your html. Replace #1 with whatever you would like to be removed.

```
$('.qode-bct-posts #1').parent().closest('a').remove();
```

You'll need to pass the id to remove specific element.

Comment: Ok, but what I need is something automatic. Maybe a code that will recognize if there is one or two or three posts, and when one is deleted